# Model shows no edges

Tags: export, edges, unreal-engine

Exported a model with default values from latest version in fbx, then imported to Unreal Engine 4. But the edges are missing, why?

[image]

Comment: can you share your blend file?

Comment: Upon exporting model for posting here i noticed that the edges only do not show when i apply UV maps and textures.

Comment: This is a very odd issue, i exported the model with a different name, added same textures, and there are no missing edges... --- oh wait there are missing edges ..... but only 1 .... hmmm

Answer (score 1):

**The answer is**: Remove any world position offset textures from your Unreal material, and the space should go away upon saving.